# Plugin for Capacitor Camera that is able to get Photos from File System Applications (Google Drive, Files)

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, camera, capacitor

Does anyone know if there is a Capacitor plugin that allows users to get photos from file solutions found on the device (ex: Google Drive)? It appears the current `@capacitor/camera` plugin does not allow you to select photos outside of gallery applications.

This was a feature in the `cordova-plugin-camera-with-exif` plugin. It showed the following screen when the user selected a pre-existing photo:

[image]

The current `@capacitor/camera` plugin only shows the following options when a user is trying to select an image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [@capawesome/capacitor-file-picker](https://capawesome.io/plugins/file-picker/). It has 2 methods you can use: `pickImages` or `pickMedia`

Comment: I looked into the `@capawesome/capacitor-file-picker` plugin and it does give you the option to pick file from the drive using the `pickFiles` option. The `pickImages` option only give the image gallery application as option. The `pickMedia` gives several app options beside the gallery apps but not google drive.